# Convert HTML form input into date php understands

Tags: php, html, datetime

I'm looking for a way to have people visiting my website enter a date through a HTML form and then use php to subtract or add time from that date they entered in. For example, in the form they will enter their Birthday and I want php to echo 5 days after their birthday.  I've looked into many ways to add dates in php, so I don't think that will be a problem.  I just can't figure out how to get php to recognize form inputs as a date.

Here is my HTML code to select the date:

```
<select name="DMonth" input type="number">
    <option>- Select Month -</option>
    <option value=1>January</option>
    <option value=2>February</option>
    ...
    <option value=12>December</option>
</select>
<select name="DDay" input type="number">
<option>- Select Day -</option>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    ...
    <option value=31>31</option>
</select>
<select name="DYear" input type="number">
    <option>- Select Year -</option>
    <option value=2013>2013</option>
    <option value=2014>2014</option>
    ...
    <option value=2022>2022</option>
</select><br>
<select name="DHour" input type="number">
<option>- Select Hour -</option>
<option value=00>12 a.m.</option>
<option value=01>1 a.m.</option>
<option value=02>2 a.m.</option>
<option value=03>3 a.m.</option>
<option value=04>4 a.m.</option>
<option value=05>5 a.m.</option>
<option value=06>6 a.m.</option>
<option value=07>7 a.m.</option>
<option value=08>8 a.m.</option>
<option value=09>9 a.m.</option>
<option value=10>10 a.m.</option>
<option value=11>11 a.m.</option>
<option value=12>12 p.m.</option>
<option value=13>1 p.m.</option>
<option value=14>2 p.m.</option>
<option value=15>3 p.m.</option>
<option value=16>4 p.m.</option>
<option value=17>5 p.m.</option>
<option value=18>6 p.m.</option>
<option value=19>7 p.m.</option>
<option value=20>8 p.m.</option>
<option value=21>9 p.m.</option>
<option value=22>10 p.m.</option>
<option value=23>11 p.m.</option>
</select>
<select name="DMin" input type="number">
<option>- Select Minute -</option>
<option value=0>00</option>
<option value=15>15</option>
<option value=30>30</option>
<option value=45>45</option>
</select>
```

and this is what I thought I would use in php

```
$DMonth=$_POST["DMonth"];
$DDay=$_POST["DDAY"];
$DYear=$_POST["DYear"];
$DHour=$_POST["DHour"];
$DMin=$_POST["DMin"];
$Bday = date_create($DYear.'-'.$DMonth.'-'.$DDay.' '.$DHour.':'.$DMin.':00');
echo date_format($Bday, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

but when I run the form, the only thing it echos is the current date and time.

Answer (score 2):

*I don't see your code for hours and minutes*

This is a bit convoluted since it is an addon to your code but will do the trick.

```
$DMonth=$_POST["DMonth"];
$DDay=$_POST["DDAY"];
$DYear=$_POST["DYear"];
$DHour=$_POST["DHour"];
$DMin=$_POST["DMin"];
$Bday = date_create($DYear.'-'.$DMonth.'-'.$DDay.' '.$DHour.':'.$DMin.':00');
echo date_format($Bday, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$datetime = new DateTime(date_format($Bday, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$datetime->modify('+5 days');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Simpler version**

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j H:i', $DYear.'-'.$DMonth.'-'.$DDay.' '.$DHour.':'.$DMin);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Birthday
$datetime->modify('+5 days');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 5 days later
```

Comment: Ok, when I run this it says that   echo $datetime('Y-m-d H:i:s');    is a Fatal Error: Function name must be a string.

Comment: Sorry. I totally left out an important part of the code. Try it now.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  With the new code it now just appears as 5 days from the current date not the input date.

Comment: Make sure you're getting all of the proper values from your form. I didn't see anything for hours and minutes but your PHP code mentions it. If it isn't really there that will cause problems.

Comment: Sorry. I copied the code before I had corrected the values to what they are in my version.  I edited yours above to reflect what mine do now.

Comment: And I edited my html form to reflect what is in mine now as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
$datetime= mktime($DHour, $DMin, 0, $DMonth, $DDay, $DYear);
```

?

See [the mktime help page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) for more information - no need to build strings or worry about formats, just provide the appropriate parameters name `Hour, Minute, Second, Month, Day, Year`

There are also a couple of problems in your html. The syntax for a select is as follows:

```
<select name="DYear">
    <option>- Select Year -</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
```

Note that the `<select>` has no `input` and that values are enclosed in quotes. There's also no need to specify `type="number"`. To correctly poarse the values as integers instead of strings, do this in your PHP:

```
$DYear = (int) $_POST["DYear"];
```

Comment: I tried this prior to the approach above and still whenever I try to echo it returns the current time (in Unix).

Comment: @AnnHolley Then I suspect you've got a problem elsewhere, I assure you `mktime()` works. See http://codepad.org/zKjz2Eey I've added some fixes to your html which might help